# Visual Studio Code can't access rails -v

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code

I don't know if it's related but I'd like to inform I use ASDF (https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) to versioning my PLs.

My problem is: I can't access rails commands on VSC terminal.

I get:

```
$ rails -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        3: from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        2: from /home/italo/Área de Trabalho/code-saga/3/cookbook_parte1/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
```

This doens't happen when I do 'ruby -v'.

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and when I run both commands (rails -v, ruby -v) in ubuntu terminal, everything works fine.

Comment: Would you check your VSCode setting in `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json` to see if there is something abnormally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the ruby plugin in vsc and restarted the terminal. Worked!